# laravel add a default value on specific column of Auth\Register Controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I used the laravel built in authentication but i add another column which is role_id. In my Auth Register controller i specify a default value on role_id which is 3

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
  return User::create([
  'name' => $data['name'],
  'email' => $data['email'],
  'role_id' => 3,
  'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
 ]);
}
```

but i got an error `Field 'role_id' doesn't have a default value` how can i fix this

Comment: Is `role_id` in your User model mass assignment variable `$fillables`?

Comment: wait i will try

Comment: it is fixed now thank you. srry just new to laravel

Comment: wait 9 minutes more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fill up the variable `$fillables` in your User model.

Do read up [Mass Assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment)